# Can't seem to setup my Django project properly

Tags: python, linux, django

I was trying the [official tutorial of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) because I want to learn it. I run **Archlinux 4.10.11-1 64 bits**.

First, I created a folder named **djangoapp** where I set my virtual environment:

`$ virtualenv djangoapp`

I set my current directory to this folder, and then I activated it:

`$ source bin/activate`

And I installed Django after:

`$ pip install django`

Following the tutorial, I ran:

`$ django-admin startproject djangoapp`

And set my current directory to **djangoapp**, and ran:

`$ python manage.py runserver`

But I'm getting the following error:

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.**

Indeed, running `env | grep DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` gets me the following result:

**DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=**

So I tried to set it manually:

`$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='djangoapp.settings'`

Running `$ python manage.py runserver` now works, but `$ django-admin help` now gets me the following error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangoapp'**

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your help!

PS: `$ python --version` gets me **Python 3.6.1**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the docs could be a little clearer about this, but `django-admin` is typically only used for running `django-admin startproject` and `manage.py` is used for the rest e.g. `./manage.py runserver`, `./manage.py migrate` etc.

Deleting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable should allow you to run both `./manage.py *` and `django-admin startproject` commands when inside the `djangoapp` folder.

I'm not sure how to do this on Archlinux, but something like `unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or `set -e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should work.

Further info: you can think of `manage.py` as a wrapper around `django-admin` that automatically sets the `PYTHONPATH` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variables. Therefore, once inside the project, you can just use `./manage.py` rather than `django-admin` to run the management commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

If I unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, I am able to run ./manage.py. But if I run django-admin, I get the following result written in red at the end:

Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).